# SAS: Interpolate a timeseries starting with a discrete time interval

Tags: sas, interpolation

I have the following data set structure:

```
date    time_in_hours   price   
Sep 03 08   9.76            98  
Sep 03 08   10.43           97  
Sep 03 08   10.98           96      
Sep 03 08   11.48           99      
Sep 04 08   2.35            98      
Sep 04 08   2.58            98.45       
Sep 04 08   3.45            96.3        
Sep 04 08   3.89            96.25       
Sep 04 08   4.18            100     
Sep 05 08   12.65           101     
Sep 05 08   12.96           100.25      
Sep 05 08   13.25           104.35      
Sep 05 08   13.78           98
```

My data is for the years 2008 and 2009. It contains a total of 504 trading days.
My objective is to interpolate prices at every half hour (eg 9.5 10 10.5 11 11.5...etc.) only for time interval between 9.5 and 16.

I have been struggling with the command interpolate / aggregate given that I must interpolate for a specific time interval for each calendar date. My final output must also contain the date, time, and price. Something like this:

```
date    time_in_hours   price   
Sep 03 08   10           98  
Sep 03 08   10.5         97  
Sep 03 08   11           96      
Sep 03 08   11.5         99      
Sep 04 08   2.5          98      
Sep 04 08   3            98.45
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Hi @itzy the final output must have the price at every half hour interval between 9.5 and 16hours every business day for the years 2008 and 2009.

Comment: How are you calculating these? Why is the price at 11 99? You really shouldn't do any interpolation; you just need to round up the time to the next half hour and then fill in missing times with the last good price.

Comment: My initial database as prices in milliseconds. So I computed the hours from the milliseconds. You think it would be best to round using the `ceil` command instead?

Comment: It is unclear why 9.76 is being _rounded_ off to 9.5 whereas 2.58 to 3. In one case, it is being increased while in the other case it is being decreased. Are you clear about the final algorithm?

Comment: @itzy for instance the best would be for me to do something similarly to this: [link](http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0101c&L=sas-l&P=5897) then take the last entry for each time interval. Good idea.

Comment: @MozanSykol thanks for spotting my typo. Would you have a good suggestion?

Comment: Have you also thought about using Proc Expand, which is very useful for converting from one time value to another, with various interpolation methods available.  You will need ETS licenced to use this procedure.

Comment: @Keith good idea I will see with the IT people here at the Uni if I have this license thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below gives you the output you have stated, but based on all comments above I am not sure it is going to solve your problem completely. Note that round(x, 0.5) takes 0.25 as the boundary - so 2.74 becomes 2.5 while 2.75 becomes 3.

```
data test;
infile datalines dsd;
input date :$20. time_in_hours price;
datalines;
Sep 03 08,9.76,98
Sep 03 08,10.43,97
Sep 0308,10.98,96
Sep 03 08,11.48,99
Sep 04 08,2.35,98
Sep 04 08,2.58,98.45
Sep 04 08,3.45,96.3
Sep 04 08,3.89,96.25
Sep 04 08,4.18,100
Sep 05 08,12.65,101
Sep 05 08,12.96,100.25
Sep 05 08,13.25,104.35
Sep 05 08,13.78,98
;
run;

proc print;
run;

data test2;
    set test(rename = (time_in_hours = old_time_in_hours));
    time_in_hours = round(old_time_in_hours, 0.5);
    if (9.5 <= time_in_hours <= 16);
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Comment: You can also consider operating on the original time in milliseconds rather than converting to hours. Of course, the logic will then change.

Comment: superb! thanks a lot. I didn't know that you can use `round` to round at 0.5. very helpful!

Comment: What about interpolating the price?